# Why is a bounty question removed without a trace?

Tags: support

I'd like to know why https://stackoverflow.com/q/38190352, a bounty question to which I've written and submitted an answer, expecting a chance at an eventual award, was removed in its entirety without a trace.

I've tried going to the address, but it returns a 404, even when I'm fully logged in.

Comment: You yourself admit in comments that it belongs on serverfault so why should it be undeleted? It's already been [asked and answered here](http://serverfault.com/questions/787859/understanding-nginx-upstream-keeplive) by you

Comment: @RobertLongson, yes, it's more suited for serverfault, but isn't exactly offtopic at so

Comment: We don't allow cross site duplicates. Given that it exists on serverfault, why would we want the same question and answer here too?

Comment: As it was a bounty question, and was on-topic for both sites, it's probably the serverfault one that should then be deleted instead.

Comment: no... it should stay on the site where it's MORE appropriate. The bounty shouldn't change that. (note, I haven't even read the question, so it MAY be more appropriate on Stack)

Comment: @Patrice, that is not true; it's actually the case that questions with a bounty cannot be voted to be closed or moved, so, what you're saying simply doesn't represent the way existing workflows were already designed and set in place.

Comment: @cnst a bounty doesn't make a question untouchable. By your premise, I could ask "What is the square root of pi", and because I put a bounty on, it's on topic.... no, just no. It's HARDER to close/delete, not impossible (if it was, your example wouldn't be deleted...). It just needs a moderator's involvement

Comment: @Patrice, you cannot set a bounty on a question less than 2 days, so, presumably in the example you outline, the question wouldn't stand a chance of not being closed in the first two days; just because something was done doesn't mean it was by design and appropriate.

Comment: So... You agree the fact a question is untouchable by bounty might not be by design or appropriate? (in a less "twisting your words" way: The bounty doesn't change anything to the on-topicness or lack thereof of the issue. If it's better on serverfault, it should go on serverfault, simply because it can reach a bigger audience there)

Comment: Also, FWIW, you were acting like a complete jerk in the comments.

Comment: *Your downvote is hate speech* HAHAHAHHAHAHAAHAHAHAHAHAHAAHH

Comment: @Wiill Wait... that was REALLY in the comments? You got to be fing kidding man :/

Comment: @Patrice my sides... someone call an ambulance...

Comment: @Patrice *"how exactly is it my fault that you have removed evidence of an obvious copy-paste through your incompetence at internet, which subsequently resulted in a bounty here, and made it impossible to migrate this question back to ServerFault where it truly belongs? Your downvote is hate speech and is entirely undeserved"*. Also, OP, why would we migrate an identical Q and indentical A?

Comment: The edit removed content that didn't belong in the question and did not *"subsequently result in a bounty"*. The bounty was placed by the OP, who was presumably aware they'd cut and pasted it. Your behaviour is inconsistent; either you think it's worth improving and answering, or should be flagged and/or closed as a cut and paste cross site dupe. You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 19):

That question was a copy-and-paste cross-post of [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/787859/understanding-nginx-upstream-keeplive) on Server Fault. It even [had the "down vote favorite" text](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38190352/revisions) that's a hallmark of quickly copied and pasted questions.

When another user edited that out, you yourself pointed out in the comments that it was a copy of that question on Server Fault. It was therefore flagged as being a cross-post and I responded to the flag (as well as flags on the comments).

I looked over at the question on Server Fault, found that you had left the exact same answer there, and decided that nothing would be lost if I removed the question on Stack Overflow. I removed the bounty and deleted the version on Stack Overflow. No information was lost.

I should point out many of your comments there (some now deleted) were rather insulting towards the editor of that question, for no reason at all. That gave me further reason to want to remove all this and clean the whole thing up.

Comment: Great, so, someone makes a mistake by removing "down vote favorite" from the question with a "wat" comment, I politely point it out, I get a downvote in return, and then my answer gets deleted (I don't even have access anymore to my own answer!), and no more bounty for me, plus I'm the one that's the jerk!  Isn't SO so great?  Who gets rewarded for being a responsible citizen?  Clearly not the people who bring out attention to the issues.  I'll have to remember next time to never again flag anything as a duplicate, especially if a bounty is being offered.  Hope you're happy with your job!

Comment: @cnst - a) Removing unnecessary wording is a good edit, b) you don't know the editor was the one to downvote your answer (nor do I), but I bet they didn't, c) your answer wasn't lost, because an exact copy of it exists on the main question, and d) you weren't the one to flag this question. Also, calling someone "stupid" and "incompetent" isn't polite by any measure.

Comment: "you don't know the editor was the one to downvote your answer (nor do I), but I bet they didn't" -- yes i do, they said it themselves that they downvoted it, and then removed their own comment; also, I didn't call anyone "stupid" or "incompetent", at this point you're just spreading misinformation.  this whole handling is entirely ridiculous and rewards people like that editor who do sloppy edits, flaming comment which they subsequently remove, & then someone else gets blamed for the whole affair in the end.  nice job at stealing bounty from someone who not only answered, but found duplicate.

Comment: @cnst so... Wait.... Removing those was a GOOD edit (on a question that was copy pasted, yes, but a good edit). And you poonted the cross site dupe yourself. Therefore, YOU pointed out it should be removed. And no one benefited or "stole" the bounty. If the question got removed,NO ONE gained rep. Seems like you want the question with the bounty to stay open just for the points

Comment: And for your answer: Brad seems to say (not a 10ker cant verify) you copy pasted it from your own serverfault answer. Nothing is lost ^^

Comment: @Patrice yes, they posted an identical answer at http://serverfault.com/q/787859, at pretty much the same time.